# Ask a step on the norm of operators

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the space $C[0,1]$ equipped with the sup norm. Let $t_0$ be an arbitrary point in $[0,1]$ and define the mapping

$$T: f \to f(t_0)$$

from $X_1 := C[0,1]$ into $X_2 := \mathbb R$. Clearly, $T$ is linear and

$$||Tf||_2=|f(t_0)| \leq \sup_{t \in [0,1]}   |f(t)|=||f||_1 $$

with equality holding for constant functions. This establishes that $T$ is also bounded with unit (operator) norm.

**Question:** My understanding of the mapping $T$ is a very usual traditional function, which if we give an input $x$, then we get $f(x)$, a real number. But how to get    $||Tf||_2=|f(t_0)| $?

Comment: It does not make sense to take the $2-$ norm of the image, since the image is a real number. $\|Tf\|=|Tf|=|f(t_0)|$. Also, the $1-$ norm is not the supremum. The supremum is the $\infty-$ norm.Your map is bounded from $L^{\infty}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, so an element of the (topological) dual.

Comment: $T$ does not take input $x$ it takes input from $X_1$ i.e. a continuous function on $[0,1]$. The output is in $X_2$ which is a real number and the norm on $X_2=\mathbb{R}$ is the absolute value.

Comment: @Samir you correctly point out my mistake. Thanks. I know $||Tf||=|Tf|$, but I don't know why $|Tf|= f(t_0)$. $f$ can be any continuous function from $[0,1]$, how it equates a specific point $f(t_0)$?

Comment: Because $T$ is defined as such. In other words, we fix and specify a real number $t_0$ and defined the map $T$ as one that takes a function $f$ and outputs $f(t_0)$. One example of such a map is the dirac delta operator, where $\delta [f]=f(0)$ i.e. it takes a function $f$ and outputs $f(0)$. Here $t_0 = 0$.

Comment: @Samir I see. I think here the idea is pointwise boundedness. For any given a specific point $t_0$, we can show that $Tf$ is bounded by $||f||_1$. And then since the upper bound $||f||_1$ does not depend on the point $t_0$ we choose, thus it is uniform boundedness. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes correct, $t_0$ is fixed and specified and regardless of its value the sup norm of $f$ is less than or equal to $f(t_0)$ by definition. Sometimes it's better to write the operator $T$ as $T_{t_0}$ to make explicit that $t_0$ is fixed and for a different $t_0$ you have a different map.